# Ropsten: Ether is not in my account, but I think it should be

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, synchronization, ropsten, balances

I'm a bit confused... I've created an Ethereum account in Ropsten, and have fed it some Ether (more than 20) via faucet.

Yesterday I synched my node with Ropsten and I could see the balance correctly, but unfortunately my local DB got corrupted... so I had to resync.

Today it's almost fully resynched, but although the transactions that put Ether into my account are already in my local copy of the DB, when I ask geth for the balance to my account, it says it's 0.

I just don't understand why is this happening, can anyone help me explain this, please?

This is what I get:

[image]

And this shows the transactions that are already uploaded to Ropsten (I haven't spent a single wei of those, as you can see):

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!! :)